# spring security 3 - Setting up a customized login

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security and i am wondering how to change the default login form.

I have set up the following configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
    <form-login login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check"
        login-page="/login" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"/>         

    <intercept-url pattern="/**"
                    access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</http>
```

In the controller I have the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("login")
public class Logincontroller {
/**
 * the logger used for print useful information
 */
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@RequestMapping(value="",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLoginView(Map<String, Object> model) {
    return WebappConstants.HOME_VIEW;
}
```

}

However when I click a url in the browser it says The page isn't redirecting properly (Firefox). I have checked firebug and have turn on the debugger in order to effectively check that this code is not making a call to my controller.

Am I doing somehting wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You denied access to the login page itself, you need to add a rule to allow it:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: where should it is added exactly?