# Spring Security hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') in config and @PreAuthorize("permitAll") not working?

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-security

I'm trying to lock down my entire app except a particular URL/method.

Here's my `applicationContext-security.xml`:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<http use-expressions="true">
    <http-basic/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/products" />
</http>
```

Here's the class with its annotation:

```
@RooWebScaffold(path = "products", formBackingObject = Product.class)
@RequestMapping("/products")
@Controller

public class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/json", headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    @PreAuthorize("permitAll")
    public String listJson() {
        return Product.toJsonArray(Product.findAllProducts());
    }

}
```

However, it's not working as expected.

If I swap the conditions around and have `permitAll` in the config and the `hasRole()` in the annotation it works as expected - but I'm trying to achieve the reverse.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm in the same place. Did you ever found a solution? How did you do it?

Comment: (>..If I swap the conditions around and have...) it is because `/**` is "above"(has higher precedence than) `/products`. If you did it (all) in security-context.xml, then you'd have to `/products/**` `permitAll` **before**  `/**` "restrict".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XML Configuration don't forget to add the following attribute:

```
      <s:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

If you are using Java Configuration don't forget to add the following annotation:

```
       @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is almost similar to question [spring security 3 - Setting up a customized login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196814/spring-security-3-setting-up-a-customized-login), if you restrict all access (pattern /**) to role_admin then how the permitAll on /product would work? Solution would be to provide IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY access on /product.

Comment: The question you mention doesn't use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation to "unlock" the login controller.  I had assumed that the annotations would override the global config, as the scope is more specific.  Perhaps the more permissive permissions on the method call won't override the more restrictive conditions at the global level.

Comment: @Ben It is other way around- the XML config override annotations (restricting or expanding permissions doesn't matter here). Imagine a scenario where you want to adjust authorization in a system that is running in production. If Spring designers allow annotations to override XML then you will have to compile the code, do regression testing and then deploy it.